# How do I add ~/bin to PATH for a systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service which calls a PHP script that creates a `tmux` session on boot.

Globally I have the most current `tmux` for the distro (V>=2.5).
The script's `USER` has a `$HOME/bin/tmux` of 2.0

What I need is for this `systemd` to use the `tmux` binary in the user's $HOME.
I have set the USER & GROUP variables in the systemd service file but it seems to call the globally installed binary.

Is it possible to explicitly set the binary that should be called for this service invocation?

If possible I'd rather not start to hardcode the path in the PHP file itself.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems terribly hackish, but prepending a `$PATH` update seems to work.
I'm on the lookout for side-effects however . . .

Example:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "PATH=/home/someUser/bin:$PATH exec /usr/bin/php /some/path/to/a/script.php"
```

Answer (score 25):

You could hardcode the `PATH` in the systemd service:

```
[Service]
Environment=PATH=/home/someUser/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

---

More flexible would be PAM. It's awfully roundabout compared to simply using `bash -c '....'`, but you can do this with PAM.

Create a new PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d` (say `/etc/pam.d/foo`) and add:

```
session    required     pam_env.so user_envfile=some-file user_readenv=1
```

And in `/home/someUser/some-file`, add:

```
PATH DEFAULT=/home/someUser/bin:${PATH}
```

Of course, you can adjust the `some-file` name to something more sensible, but the path in `user_envfile` has to be relative to the user's home directory (the user that you set in `User=` in the service).

Then in the service file, in the `[Service]` section, add (`foo` being the file in `/etc/pam.d` created earlier):

```
PAMName=foo
```

Now, when you start the service (after reloading, etc.), the `session` modules in `/etc/pam.d/foo` will be run, which in this case is just [`pam_env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pam_env.8.html). `pam_env` will load environment variables from `/etc/environment`, subject to constraints in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, and then the user environment from `~/some-file`. Since `PATH` is set to a default value in `/etc/environment`, the user environment prepends to this default value.

Here, the default value of `user_envfile` is `.pam_environment`, which is also read by the PAM configuration of other things like SSH or LightDM login, etc. I used a different file here in case you don't want to affect these things. You could remove the `user_envfile=...` and use the default `~/.pam_environment`. you could also just use an existing PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d` which has `user_readenv=1`, but other PAM modules may cause unwanted side effects.

Comment: I really appreciate the `pam` approach as it did not occur to me. It, unfortunately, creates a massive amount of complexity for something fairly trivial. Your `PATH` variable is effectively the same as my own and unless I hear something different the way I'll go.

Comment: @Mark I agree, I'd only use it if an existing PAM configuration and environment file for my purpose or if I really needed pam_env's slightly higher flexibility (you can't do something like `bar=x foo=${bar}` in systemd, but it's possible in pam_env)

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm digging up a slightly dated post, but I too was trying to figure out how I could get the PATH/environment variables configured so thaty I could get the scheduler to run automatically when the server is running.

I did find a solution that works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10

I provided a full write-up of how to [install Airflow and PostgreSQL](https://ryanmerlin.com/2019/07/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) on the backend on the link [here](https://ryanmerlin.com/2019/07/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/).

**from the later part of my article
Essentially it comes down to making a specific change to the airflow-scheduler.system file.

This is one of the ‘gotchas’ for an implementation on Ubuntu. The dev team that created Airflow designed it to run on a different distribution of linux and therefore there is a small (but critical) change that needs to be made so that Airflow will automatically run when the server is on. The default systemd service files initially look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, this will not work as the ‘EnvironmentFile’ protocol doesn’t fly on Ubuntu 18. Instead, comment out that line and add in :

```
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

You will likely want to create a systemd service file at least for the Airflow Scheduler and also probably the Webserver if you want the UI to launch automatically as well. Indeed we do want both in this implementation, so we will be creating two files, airflow-scheduler.service & airflow-webserver.service. Both of which will be copied to the /etc/systemd/system folder. These are as follows:

---

## airflow-scheduler.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
#airflow-webserver.service
```

---

## airflow-webserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin/airflow webserver -p 8085 --pid /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally, with both of those files copied to the /etc/systemd/systemd folder by way of a superuser copy command sudo cp  it is time to hit the ignition:

sudo systemctl enable airflow-scheduler
sudo systemctl start airflow-scheduler
sudo systemctl enable airflow-webserver
sudo systemctl start airflow-webserver

Answer (score -1):

In a service I was setting up (Apache Airflow) I had an Environment File set.

In my `/etc/systemd/system/airflow` file, I had this line:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
```

Opening this environment file, I added the line I needed, in my case:

```
SCHEDULER_RUNS=5
PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Add whatever paths to the executables you need to be able to be reached by the service here and you should be ok. Worked well for me.

Comment: For `Environment=`, the $ character has no special meaning. `$PATH` doesn't seem to get expanded when written in an environment file either