# how to execute script on shutdown for wmctrl -l?

Tags: startup, systemd

system:
ubuntu 20

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Scripts at Start and Stop

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true  
ExecStop=/home/user/same_test

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

same_test:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo test >> home/user/same_test_echo.txt (works)
wmctrl -l >> /home/user/same_test.txt (don't work)
```

Result is:

- same_test.txt is empty (don't work)
- same_test_echo.txt contain test (works)

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 system? as they are usually headless.  (Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are different products to the far more common *year.month* systems, ie. 20 != 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 - Check the PATH

The first step is to see if the problem lies in where the commands are located:

```
$ type -a echo

echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo

$ type -a wmctrl

wmctrl is /usr/bin/wmctrl
```

The `echo` command is built into the shell and also located in the `/bin` directory, which is the most popular directory for programs.

The `wmctrl` command is located in the `/usr/bin` directory which may not be part of your systemd `PATH`.

So similar to this question:

- [How do I add ~/bin to PATH for a systemd service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014480/how-do-i-add-bin-to-path-for-a-systemd-service)

The solution there was to add a line to systemd service:

```yaml
[Service]
Environment=PATH=/home/someUser/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Another option is to hard-code the directory for the command when you call it: `/usr/bin/wmctrl`.

---

### Option 2 - `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

**NOTE:** This is generic option for those *Start Up* and doesn't apply to *Shut down* like the OP is doing.

If the path wasn't the problem, the next step is to check the `WantedBy` option:

- [Why do most systemd examples contain WantedBy=multi-user.target?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506347/why-do-most-systemd-examples-contain-wantedby-multi-user-target)

The answer there explains:

> Note that a Wants or WantedBy only says that the system should startup one service whenever another service or target is also started, but it specifies nothing at all about the startup/shutdown order. If you need service B to be already running when service A starts up, you'd need to add Before=A.service in the B.service file to explicitly specify the start-up order dependency.

Consider the fact the GUI may not even be running when your script is run. So there are no windows for `wmctrl -l` to report.

If this is the problem `After` (during startup) rather than `WantedBy` is a likely solution.

---

### Option 3 - Use `/bin/true`

From comments in this Q&A:

- [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)

Replace:

```
RemainAfterExit=true
```

With:

```
RemainAfterExit=/bin/true
```

**Note:** `true` is a shell builtin and a command:

```
$ type -a true
true is a shell builtin
true is /bin/true
```

Comment: I think the problem is service running on shutdown after all apps and maybe gui closed.
I tried: Before=graphical.target but don't work
How to run service before all apps and gui closed when shutdown/reboot?

Comment: @IgorShumakov Here is some additional reading while I dig a little deeper for a perfect fit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284598/systemd-how-to-execute-script-at-shutdown-only-not-at-reboot

Comment: Thanks. The service is executing on shutdown but problem is wmctl -l is still empty